# Reference a Recyclerview that was in a fragment in Appcompat activity?

Tags: java, android, visual-studio, user-interface, intellij-idea

Hey so I have a recyclerview and a recyclerview adapter as shown below. However, this recyclerview adapter was inflated inside an activity that extends fragment. This time I want to use it in an activity that extends AppCompatActivity, How do I do that?

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard,container,false);
    mRecyclerView=(RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.ID);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mAdapterDashBoard=new AdapterDashBoard(this);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapterDashBoard);
    return view;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use the same code inside your onCreate() method of the Activity

```
// Initialize recycler view
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.ID);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
mAdapterDashBoard=new AdapterDashBoard(this);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapterDashBoard);
```